# simple graphical program

Tags: java, c++, qt, networking

I have made a small C++ network application. It outputs the packet exchanges in a file. The output looks like this:

```
From..to..message
1 2 "hi"
2 3 "hi"
3 2 "hi back"
2 1 "hi back"
```

So the first field is the source, the second the destination, and the third the message.
I have 10 nodes in total, all displayed in line (0...1...2...etc...9), and each output line corresponds to a message between consecutive nodes.

My problem is that the output is not that easy to read as it gets bigger and bigger. I would like to have a very small application (in java or qt, for example, whichever requires the less lines to implement), that reads from that output and makes a small GUI application out of it, so that all nodes appear in the GUI window (from 0 to 9, spaced equally, encircled), and every time I press the right arrow (forward) or left arrow (backward) it reads one line from the output, and displays an arrow from the source to the destination, and over that arrow would be displayed the message.
So something like this:

```
              hi
0     1     2---->3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

I am opened to other suggestions regarding the GUI description, I'm not a graphic designer  at all, all I know is that I would like a GUI to make my output easier to interpret.
The output structure could also be changed to something else if it would make it easier to parse.

Comment: Yes this is possible.What is your question?

Comment: My question is how easy is it to do, and which framework would make it even easier, and if it's really easy, then how to do it, what would be the general structure of such a program. I'm new to GUI programming, so I'd like a few pointers. I don't want to spend too much time on it, not more than say one or two hours. it's just to help me read my output file.

Comment: How about using [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to visualize it for you instead of writing a GUI program on your own? It would cost you less time since you can modify your output format to fit `GraphViz`'s input format.

Comment: Yes sure I can modify the output format, and I'm opened to suggestions as to what would be the best and easiest solution. However I don't know graphviz. Is it easy to use ? Does it allow a 'video' mode, where the graph can evolve in time, or is it just an image ? Because how would you represent the different message exchange with two nodes, if it's just a static graph ? Additionnally, what would my output have to look like ?

Comment: Ease of use: see page 3 of [Drawing graphs with _dot_](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) for a simple example on input format.  
"Video" mode: generate multiple images and use any image viewer with slideshow functionality.

Comment: Well if for each message, an image has to be generated, it's not very efficient. There might be hundreds of messages. How about using java, how easy would it be ?

Comment: [This thread](http://graphviz.org/content/animated-visualization) discussed about almost the same application as yours.

Comment: okay, it seems doable then. Can you please make it an answer, and give an example of how it could be done with graphviz, given the output structure I provided, or another one of your choice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

To generate something looks like

```
        hi
1     2---->3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

You should generate a plain text file:

```
digraph G {
    { rank = same; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; };
    2 -> 3 [label="hi"];
}
```

Then, invoke `dot -Tpng <text file name> -o <output image file name>`, and you can get a image which looks like:

[image: Example figure]

To make into animation, you may want to change output format as `gif` and use other tools to compose an animated GIF.